# Solving $Ax=b$ when $x$ and $b$ are given.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares

I am trying to study least square and linear regression and I understand the solution for $Ax = b$ when x is the unknown and the LS solution is given by $(A^TA)^{-1}A^TA$. Now, I was wondering if something similar exists when A is unknown. I was wondering if I do the corresponding:

$$
Ax=b
$$
$$
x^TA^T = b
$$

Therefore, $A^T = (xx^T)^{-1}xb$ or $A = b^Tx^T ((xx^T)^{-1})^T$

Comment: Note that if $x$ and $b$ have $n$ components, you have $2n$ pieces of data whle $A$ has $n^2$ components, so your system is underdetermined for $n \gt 2$

Comment: Thanks. Ok, I understand it now. So, this has no unique solutions.

Comment: There are many matrices $A$ such that $Ax=b$ if $x,b$ are known.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $xx^T$ is a rank one matrix, it is not invertible and $(xx^T)^{-1}$ does not exist. Your system is therefore [underdetermined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system).

The best way to obtain a (pseudo-)unique solution is either to replace $(xx^T)^{-1}$ by the [*Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of $x^Tx$ or to use a regularization procedure (like the [Tikhonov one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization), where you would replace $(xx^T)^{-1}$ by $(xx^T+\lambda I)^{-1}$ with $\lambda > 0$).

Answer (score 5):

You are basically asking for a linear transformation that maps one vector $x$ to another vector $b$. With no other constraints, there are infinitely many answers except in the special case of one dimension.

A linear mapping $A:\mathbb{R}^{n}  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ requires $n$ linearly independent equations in order to be fully specified. This means you would need $n$ equations $Ax_1=b_1,Ax_2=b_2,...,Ax_n=b_n$  (or more simply $AX=B$ where $X$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices) in order to get a unique answer.

Answer (score 3):

If $x$ is zero, an $A$ exists (if and) only if $b=0$ and in this case, $A$ can be chosen arbitrarily.
If $x$ is nonzero, then any $A$ such that $Ax=b$ is given by
$$\tag{1}
A=bx^\dagger+Z(I-xx^\dagger),
$$
where $Z$ is any matrix of the same size as $A$ and $x^\dagger=x^*/\|x\|_2^2$. You may verify that
$$
Ax=b(x^\dagger x)+Z(I-xx^\dagger)x=b+Z(x-x(x^\dagger x))=b+Z(x-x)=b
$$
using $x^\dagger x=x^*x/\|x\|_2^2=1$.
The form (1) follows simply from recasting $Ax=b$ as a linear system for the matrix $A$ and from the fact that any solution to $Bz=c$ is given by $z=z_0+w$, where $z_0$ is any solution to $Bz=c$ and $w$ is in the kernel of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as Wahba's problem. Grace Wahba posed this problem in 1965 when attempting to determine satellite attitude from a sequence of measurements in the body-fixed frame and a known vector quantity, like gravity or Earth's magnetic field in the Earth-fixed frame.

There are a few papers solving this in different ways. Some recent papers by F. Landis Markley provide solution steps, for example [here](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19930015542), from a 1993 NASA conference paper titled:

```
Attitude determination using vector observations: A fast optimal matrix algorithm
```

There are other approaches but they all minimize Wahba's cost function, which is a weighted version of |Ax-b|, which will become zero, or nearly zero with the right A matrix.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).